# Firefox link to javascript function opens a new window when not intended

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, hyperlink, href

I have this problem where when I have this html in firefox it opens a new window

```
<a style="float:right;" 
href='javascript:window.location.href="#";'onClick="javascript:addNewRecord();">
New Record</a>
```

I have tried self.location, window.location, #body, and #h1 as the href.

Originally I had the code as, but in firefox that did not do anything but open a fresh window, and not perform my function.  The code works perfect in chrome.

```
<a style="float:right;" href="javascript:addNewRecord();">New Record</a>
```

Comment: Please show us your addNewRecord() function. I believe that problem is hiding there.
P.S. You don't need to add javascript "protocol" for onclick events. They exists only for javascript and nothing else :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How your code behaves depends entirely on what the addNewRecord() function does (including what it returns).

Without seeing inside that function it's hard to tell, but I'd say that what is happening is inside there.

Note that what you put in the href="" part probably is not affecting the behaviour you're seeing.

Answer (score 10):

The canonical inline way is

```
<a style="float:right;" href="#"
onClick="addNewRecord(); return false">New Record</a>
```

or better:

```
<a style="float:right;" href="#"
onClick="return addNewRecord()">New Record</a>
```

where addNewRecord returns false at the end of the function

---

An even better way is

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("addLink").onclick=addNewRecord;
}
function addNewRecord() {
  ...
  return false;
}
```

plus

```
<style>
#addLink { float:right }
</style>
```

and

```
<a href="#" id="addLink">New Record</a>
```

Since abusing the HREF on a link going nowhere just to get a pointer is frowned upon, you may consider a `<span>` with an onclick and a cursor:pointer. It does need more effort to make such an element accessible to for example screen readers.

Comment: *href="#"* breaks UI flow on longer pages since it jumps the browser view back up to the top of the page.

Comment: @jbalyo nope - the return false or a preventDefault will stop that from happening.

Comment: I use href="javascript:void(0);" to avoid the "flow" problem.

Comment: That also breaks if JS is off

Answer (score 4):

try :

```
onClick="addNewRecord();return false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a onclick="javascript:addNewRecord();">New Record</a>
```